# Optimising loops for pixel processing

Tags: optimization, image-processing, opencv

I'm implementing an algorithm (in OpenCV) that iterates over every pixel in an image, and for each pixel calculates block matches with pixels in the neighbourhood in order to evalaute the similarity of these neighbouring pixels. A "naive" implementation with very deep loops is very slow, so I was wondering how I might try to improve the performance. The following is an extract of my current code:

```
for(nCh=1;nCh<=channels;nCh++) { // Loop over three channels

  for(i=0;i<h;i++) { // "vertical" loop

    for(j=0;j<w;j++) { // "horizontal" loop

      for (si=-sw_height; si<sw_height; si++){ // vertical search window loop

        for (sj=-sw_width; sj<sw_width; sj++){ // horizontal search window loop

            dist = 0;

            for (blki=0; blki<blk_height; blki++){ // block match loop

              for (blkj=0; blkj<blk_width; blkj++){ // block match loop

                current_pxl = data[(i+blki)*step+(j+blkj)*channels+nCh];  

                search_pxl  = data[(i+blki+si)*step+(j+blkj+sj)*channels+nCh]; 

                dist += pow((current_pxl - search_pxl),2); 

              }

            }

          // ... further processing

        }

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your're doing non-local means denoising or self-similarity features?  If so, even with the best optimizations it won't be good enough for real-time even with small images, block sizes, and search windows.  To approach real-time, check out some approaches using GPUs -- the NVidia CUDA SDK comes with a sample application for NLM-denoising that runs at over 100 fps on my card.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this is indeed broadly the type of algorithm I'm implementing. I like your suggestion regarding the GPU - in fact I've love to dabble with general purpose GPU programming but I believe my current graphics card, a Nvidia Quadro fx570 with "just" 16 stream processors is comparatively slow as GPU's go? I'd be happy with a non real time solution with a reasonable processing time (<2 minutes) for a large-ish image (6+ megapixel image). If you did have any more comments on GPU processing I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Also another option I'm currently looking at is to pre-calculate the block similarity (for a sum of absolute difference metric instead of a sum of squared differences) so as to avoid to the inner most two loops. Somewhat akin to using an integral image in face detection algorithms.

Comment: If you're interested further in GPU approaches for this type of algorithm, check out this NVIDIA tech report: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/C/html/C/src/imageDenoising/doc/imageDenoising.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `pow` in the innermost loop. Don't.

Also you're doing a lot of index calculation in there.
I bet you can move some out that out of the inner loop.

You should be able to get it so your inner loop looks more like this:

```
          for (blkj = 0; blkj < blk_width; blkj++, pc += channels, ps += channels){
            int diff = (*pc - *ps); 
            dist += (diff * diff); 
          }
```

And then, you might even want to unroll it a bit.

BTW, a little more whitespace might help :-)

Comment: Specifically replace the pow(x,2) with (x*x). You'd think the compiler would make this replacement for you, but often it won't for reasons I won't get into here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Mike, I'll try them out, particular moving some of the indexing about. @Mark thats very interesting, I would have assumed that replacement would happen too. I'm using gcc 4.5.2

Comment: @trican: It has no way of knowing `pow` hasn't been replaced by something completely different. I like it when the compiler makes good use of registers, etc., but I never *depend* on it to do what I could very well do myself.

Comment: wow just replacing the pow(x,2) with x*x reduced the run time by 75%! Onwards to improving the address indexing ... :-)

Comment: @Mike, I wonder could you elaborate on the code segment that you've entered above. It definitely looks interesting but I don't get it, probably mostly because I've never seen an update statement in a for-loop done like that.

Comment: @trican: You mean the increment part? It's three assignment statements separated by commas. You can do anything you want between the semicolon and the right paren. (You could also just do it at the bottom of the loop - same thing.) You set `int *pc, *ps` before you enter the loop, and then just increase them by the right amount every time around.